# How can I get Posts related to the user in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
#user/application mdodels.py
class ShowProfilePageView(DetailView):
    model=User
    template_name="users/profile.html"
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        users=User.objects.all()
        nested_posts = {}
        context = super(ShowProfilePageView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        page_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['page_user'] = page_user

        return context
#post model
    class Posts(models.Model):
        choices1 = Category.objects.all().values_list('name','name')
        choice_list=[]
        for item in choices1:
            choice_list.append(item)
        default2="Words are powerful, and, when used well, they can"
        default1= "Words are powerful, and, when used well, they can incite people to both good and evil. While everyone has the right to say whatever he or she wants, those with influence over wants, those with influence over wants, those with influence over and thats"
category = models.CharField(max_length =30, choices = choice_list, default=choice_list[1])
        title= models.CharField(default=default2, max_length=50)
        content= models.TextField(max_length=2555,default=default1)
        data_posted =models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, default ="default.jpg", upload_to="images/")
        snippet = models.TextField(default=default2, max_length=255)
        likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blogpost_like')



        def number_of_likes(self):
            return self.likes.count()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Posts, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            header_image= Image.open(self.header_image.path)
            if header_image.height  > 300 or header_image.width > 300:
                output_size = (500,300  )
                header_image.thumbnail(output_size)
                header_image.save(self.header_image.path)
        
        @property
        def number_of_comments(self):
            return BlogComment.objects.filter(blogpost_connected=self).count()

        def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse ('home')
```

I am able to get the `id` but not the `posts` related to that `id`. what i am able to retrieve is the user's name, profile description, and profile image.the `class Posts` is in charge of taking in the information and storing Posts. I would like to be able to call posts in `ShowProfilePageView` then I could show both the `User` infomration and the posts that are connected to that user. I can currently call the `User` information but not the Posts related to the user

```
#tempalte Profile.html
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="media">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ page_user.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="account-heading">{{ page_user }}</h2>
      <h3 class="text-secondary">{{ page_user.profile.profile_description }}</h3>
        
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you add the models?

Comment: sure! hopefully what I added will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I am sure there are a million ways to do it, but this seemed to work.

```
 #from users.models
class ShowProfilePageView(DetailView):
model=User
template_name="users/profile.html"
paginate_by = 5

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    users=User.objects.all()
    nested_posts = {}
    context = super(ShowProfilePageView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    page_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    context['page_user'] = page_user
    posts=Posts.objects.filter(author=page_user).order_by('-data_posted')
    context['posts'] = posts
    return context
```